# kxmlgui, XMLGUI, application port to plain Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, kde-plasma

I'm considering taking on a porting project, currently it's written in kxmlgui.  It was originally intended to run on KDE3 + Qt3, but the application's only KDE requirement is from its `.rc` kxmlgui file.  The project is partially ported to Qt4, and finishing that should not be a problem.  What would it take to port it all the pure Qt4?  Is there a plain Qt4 XMLGUI type library, as an alternative to kxmlgui?  Or better a way to convert with a tool's help?

I appreciate anyone who can help, and has knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see of kxmlgui, it shouldn't be that hard to port it to **QML**, which is also a declarative SGML description of the ui.

This is what is used in KDE4 Plasmoids and is available from Qt 4.7 on.

Comment: First I'm assuming you mistakenly called QML SGML markup.  From my limited understanding, I was under the impression that it was JavaScript based.  In addition, it seemed inappropriate for a standard desktop GUI application. This is a real application, not some type of desktop widget.  If QML is used for regular desktop applications, It looks like nothing exists to lighten the porting load.  So if I'm manually doing everything anyway, I'd rather choose something more appropriate.

Comment: Regardless thank you for your help, I appreciate that you spent your time for my question.

Comment: QML describes the Ui. The business logic can be javascript OR C++/Qt. But if you want a QWidget-based app, you'd have to find a way to translate the kxmlgui into Qt .ui file, I guess

Comment: well your the only one who answered, so I gave you the accept